# Deploying .net Informix application

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, odbc, informix

I have a .NET client application which communicates with Informix database.
Now the application is simply not working. To resolve the application I have to install the Informix SDK on each client(which is 250mb file).....then configure ODBC driver manually….
This is completely insane to install 250 MB sdk on each system to install my application which Is in kb’s….is it necessary to install SDK on each system?

I also want to remove the manual step of configuring ODBC driver on each system.

Can someone please point me to the tutorial which describes the deployment of Informix application?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the whole informix SDK, but you need "Informix Connect" which includes the informix database drivers. Informix connect is 12MB.

I think you can script the ODBC Driver configuration, but you have also to set the informix SETNET configuration for your Informix database. This parameters are stored in the registry.

The keyword for deploying Setnet on the Clients is "Silent Installation", you can install Informix Connect in Silent Mode. 
See: [Performing a silent installation of Informix and client products](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cpi.doc/ids_cpi_018.htm)

For setnet32 it is possible to save your configuration in a *.nfx file and restore it with "setnet32 -l filename.nfx".

Comment: if u know of any tutorial which explain these steps then please point to that....

Comment: Also, How can i automate the process of setting SETNET configuration?

Comment: Unfortunely i had no tutorial which explains the installation steps for your requirement. But i added some information for Silent installation. Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: When i download Informix connect it asks for "What is your current reason for downloading"...are we suppose to buy it before going to production???

Comment: also if you can help me with download of informix connect...when i search it shows size as 12 MB but when i download the size becomes ~240MB...connect.4.10.TC1DE.WIN.zip is the file i got...from where to download 12MB version

Comment: Sorry, the Informix connect installation is 240 MB. I read the size for the informix-connect only on the download page and did no double check. 
...and i think you need some kind of licence for Informix connect, but im not familiar with Informix licencing. 
We use informix for our customer but fortunatly i had not to deal with licence and informix connect installation.